# Replace USB diode with something else to reduce voltage drop

Tags: voltage, mosfet, lithium-ion, input, selector

So I've made this circuit with a MOSFET and an Op Amp to select a voltage input to my battery. I sort of based it off the voltage selector circuit on the Arduino Uno board, but inversed since that defaults to the barrel plug, but I want to default to USB.

I like it, but that diode creating voltage-drop across the USB input is slightly bothersome and reduces the USB voltage to 4.49V. Is there any way to remove the diode from this circuit and replace it with something else (ex. a MOSFET)? I couldn't figure out how.

The first MOSFET at DC In is for reverse voltage protection, while the second is for switching inputs.

Here's the part numbers in case you happen to want to look at the datasheets:

- P-MOSFET: AOSS21311C
- OP Amp: LM321SN3T1G

[image: Schematic]

EDIT: Second question: I think the fact that the voltages at the inputs are below VSS relative to the Op Amp might damage it, am I right about that? In which case I'd have to redesign the circuit somehow. I'm not even sure they make P MOSFETS with a Vgs that goes up to 30V, I couldn't find a single one.

Comment: Are you taking 5A? That diode will drop a lot less at say 0.5A.

Comment: The USB shouldn't exceed 2A I think due to the resistance of the cables/ports... I was also considering adding a 2A PTC fuse to the USB input. The DC Input on the other hand can go up to 4A. The regulator will shut off at 4A output current, it has overcurrent protection. (4 parallel Li-ion cells = 1A per battery, so 4A is a good charging current)

Comment: There exist integrated solutions both for the diode and the or condition.  https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-or-controllers-ideal-diodes/758?k=ideal%20diode

Comment: Oh, that seems useful. An IC designed for it would be the best solution. But unfortunately my situation here seems to spec-out nearly all of them. They have to be able to take 30V at 4A. And the ones that use an external MOSFET are crazy expensive for some reason, like $3.00+. That's like over double the cost of everything here (even @ qty 1)

Comment: Basically I'm trying to make a universal input for charging the battery here, made to take 6V, 12V, or 24VDC power from a power supply or solar panel. But I want it to default to USB since the USB input will likely be more stable/dependable than whatever's connected to DC In.